# Find a least upper bound for $3^{x+y-4}+(x+y+1)2^{7-x-y}-3(x^2+y^2)$ with some constraint?

Tags: inequality, optimization, systems-of-equations

This is a question in vietnamese national math exam at the end of 12th grade.

> Given x,y are real numbers which satisfy the condition:
>   $x+y+1=2(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{y+3})$

Find a $m$ such that:

> $3^{x+y-4}+(x+y+1)2^{7-x-y}-3(x^2+y^2)\leq m$

The answer as given is $m \geq 148/3$, which contradicts with wolfram alpha (it claims that it has no global maximum). I'm unable to find a counter example due to the non-linear nature of the system of equations.

I hope that math SE could help.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** This is NOT an answer. This is just a long comment with some thought.

---

Let $u=\sqrt{x-2}, v=\sqrt{y+3}\implies x=u^2+2,y=v^2-3$

We have
$$u^2+2+v^2-3+1=2(u+v)$$
$$(u-1)^2+(v-1)^2=2$$

Set $u=\sqrt2 \sin t+1,v=\sqrt2 \cos t+1$, $t\in[\frac{\pi}4,\frac{3\pi}4]$

Substitute back to original equation:

\begin{align}
x+y+1&=(\sqrt2 \sin t+1)^2+2+(\sqrt2 \cos t+1)^2-3+1\\&=4+2\sqrt2(\sin t+\cos t)
\end{align}

Denote $L=x+y+1$.

Extremum of $L$ is obtained when $t=\frac{\pi}4$. (By differentitation) We get $L=8.$

Back to the inequality,

$$3^{L-5}+L\cdot2^{8-L}-3(x^2+y^2)\le m$$

Comment: When you set $u=\sqrt{2}\sin{t}+1$, is it valid if the domain of $u$ and the domain of $\sqrt{2}\sin{t}+1$ don't coincide ?

Comment: Yes. It should be stated that: As $u\ge 0$, $\sqrt2 \sin t +1\ge 0\implies \frac{\pi}4\le t \le \frac{3\pi}4$. I shall add the condition.

Comment: I mean $\sqrt{2}\sin{t}+1\leq\sqrt{2}+1$, whereas $u$ only needs to be zero or positive, so you are unnecessarily restricting the domain of $u$.

Comment: This condition is derived from $x+y+1=2(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{y+3})\iff (u-1)^2+(v-1)^2=2$. If you notice, $u,v$ have to be on the circle.

Comment: Fine, I understood. Your substitution is valid then :). What do you think of the negative result of Wolfram? I entered with "optimize (expression) with constraint (...)". Is it that I entered it wrongly or is it too complex for Wolfram to solve it ?